# Expressing a function in terms of x, y and z in multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus

Suppose $w=\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}+\displaystyle\frac{y}{z}, x=e^{5t}, y=2+\sin(2t), z=2+\cos(5t)$.

Use the chain rule to find $\displaystyle\frac{dw}{dt}$ as a function of x,y, z and t. Do not rewrite x, y and z in terms of t, and DO NOT rewrite $e^{5t}$ as x. This answer should be an expression in x, y, z.

---

I'm not sure how to write the expression in terms of x, y and z. I have tried solving for t in the equation for x, but this is not the case. I have that my derivative is:

$\displaystyle\frac{dw}{dt}=\displaystyle\frac{5x}{y} + 2(\displaystyle\frac{1}{z} - \displaystyle\frac{1}{y^{2}})\cos(\displaystyle\frac{2(lnx)}{5})+\displaystyle\frac{y(5\sin(lnx))}{z^2}$

By having that $t=\displaystyle\frac{lnx}{5}$

How can I solve this problem following the guidelines that are proposed above? I was as well thinking of converting t using the other parameters that we are given, say for y or z, but it would be extremely messy in that case. I'm sure that i have a correct expression for the derivative. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By chain rule, we know that

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$

To evaluate $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t}$ with $w=\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{z}$, $x=e^{5t}$, $y=2+\sin(2t)$ and $z=2+\cos(5t)$ under the imposed conditions, they want you to do two things:

1) Differentiate $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$, $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}$ and $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}$ like you normally would without substituting in their equivalent functions of $t$; for instance, you would want to write $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\dfrac{1}{y}$ instead of $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \dfrac{1}{2+\sin(2t)}$.

[I did notice, though, that the question first says that they want $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t}$ as a function of $x$, $y$, $z$, and $\color{red}{t}$, but later on it says the answer should be an expression in just $x$, $y$, and $z$...which one is it?  From the way it's worded, it seems like they want the final answer in terms of $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ (well, that's what makes the most sense to me in this case...otherwise writing the partial derivative as a function of $x$, $y$, and $z$ defeats the purpose of the second imposed condition seen below).]

2) Differentiate $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, and $\dfrac{dz}{dt}$ like you normally would as functions of $t$; for example, since $x=e^{5t}$, you would want to write $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=5e^{5t}$ instead of $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 5x$ (since $x=e^{5t}$).

Following these two guidelines then will get you the answer they want, although it will look slightly complicated.

Comment: Yes i have done the same as you, however, how should i write my equation? Just in terms of t, x, y, z without rewriting at the end? (so just normally differentiating the function and leaving it as it is?)

Comment: @fogvajarash That's what it seems like to me.  I would at least clean it up a little instead of leaving it like 
$$\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\left(5e^{5t}\right) +\left(\ldots\right)\left(\ldots\right) +\left(\ldots\right)\left(\ldots\right)$$